# Consigo pegar qual "Serie" está selecionada em uma legenda de um gráfico primefaces?

Tags: javascript, jquery, primefaces

Estou tentando pegar qual item da legenda está selecionado em um gráfico de linhas do primefaces.

Já tentei algo como `plot.series.isSelected`, o máximo que consegui pegar são os valores maximo e minimo dos eixos x e y usando: `plot.axes.yaxis.min`

Alguém sabe se consigo pegar qual coluna está selecionada no gráfico(legenda) e os valores que contém aquele item?